# Problem sending video and image file to my database using axios and FormData()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, form-data

I am newbie in React. I am trying to create a react web app than enables me POST data (with image and video files) to an API endpoint.

The first challenge is that the files (image and videos) get to my database(MSsql) as a blob.[See image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfUKo.png)

```
{
      "id": 18,
      "propertyId": "11",
      "category": "Shortlet",
      "roomType": "3 bedrooms",
      "location": "Lekki phase1",
      "amount": 9000000,
      "thumbnailImageUrl": "blob:http://localhost:3000/97888e66-2fa8-4198-bf71-4f80f5a49b8c",
      "interiorVideoUrl": "blob:http://localhost:3000/e111b303-007c-45bc-b80b-f017d4d559e1",
      "compoundVideoUrl": "blob:http://localhost:3000/fc167a1f-a1bd-4952-a851-534cb87ae8be",
      "streetVideoUrl": "blob:http://localhost:3000/d7a7aca6-fd56-4fb6-8e36-7e75bae3ed3a",
      "dateCreated": "2022-09-30T07:31:22.66",
      "dateModified": "2022-09-30T07:31:22.66",
      "isPropertyAvailable": true,
      "isDeleted": false
}
```

This is the code used to POST the data to the endpoint[using setState method to get the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYfqd.png)
[POSTing the data using axios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBD0W.png)

First Question: I am not sure the blob files will be useful when retrieving them on the client-side from the database (especically on a different device)?

The 2nd Challenge: Someone advised i use FormData object to solve the blob issue. When i tried that, i get an axios 415 error in the console as shown below. The error persisted after console logging the FormData object to ensure all d data r passed to d endpoint.[appending my data using FormData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQxI2.png). Here is my code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import styled from "styled-components";

function AdminAddProperty() {
  const categoryOptions = ["Rent", "Shortlet"];



const bedroomsOptions = [
    "Shared",
    "1 bedroom",
    "2 bedrooms",
    "3 bedrooms",
    "4+ bedrooms",
  ];



const areaOptions = [
    "Oniru",
    "Lekki phase1",
    "Lekki phase1 (right)",
    "Ikate",
    "Salem",
    "Ilasan",
    "Jakande",
    "Osapa",
    "Agungi",
    "Ologolo",
    "Igboefon",
    "Idado",
    "Newroad",
    "Chevron",
    "Conservation road",
    "Orchid road",
    "Ikota",
    "VGC",
    "Ajah",
    "Awoyaya",
  ];



const [category, setCategory] = useState();
const [roomType, setRoomType] = useState();
const [location, setLocation] = useState();
const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
const [thumbnailImageUrl, setThumbnailImageUrl] = useState();
const [interiorVideoUrl, setInteriorVideoUrl] = useState();
const [compoundVideoUrl, setCompoundVideoUrl] = useState();
const [streetVideoUrl, setStreetVideoUrl] = useState();


console.log(category);
console.log(roomType);
console.log(location);
console.log(price);



const handleCategoryChange = (e) =>{
    setCategory(e.target.value)
  }

const handleBedroomsChange = (e) =>{
    setRoomType(e.target.value)
  }

const handleAreaChange = (e) =>{
    setLocation(e.target.value)
  }

const handlePriceChange = (e) =>{
    setPrice(e.target.value)
  }

const handleimgChange = (e) =>{
    setThumbnailImageUrl(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))
  };

const handleIntVidChange = (e) =>{
    setInteriorVideoUrl(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))
  }

const handleCompChange = (e) =>{
    setCompoundVideoUrl(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))
  }

const handleStreetChange = (e) =>{
    setStreetVideoUrl(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))
  }




const handleFormSubmit = async (e) => {
    //created a FormData object
    var formData = new FormData();

    // const string = "string"
    
    // //update the FormData object
    formData.append('propertyId', 18);
    formData.append('category', category);
    formData.append('roomType', roomType);
    formData.append('location', location);
    formData.append('amount', price );
    formData.append('thumbnailImageUrl',thumbnailImageUrl);
    formData.append('interiorVideoUrl', interiorVideoUrl );
    formData.append('compoundVideoUrl', compoundVideoUrl );
    formData.append('streetVideoUrl', streetVideoUrl);
    formData.append('isPropertyAvailable', true);




    console.log('%O',formData)
    console.log([...formData])
    console.dir(formData,{
      Depth: null
    })
    
    console.log(thumbnailImageUrl)


    e.preventDefault();
    await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://ampeer-001-site1.gtempurl.com/api/Admin/CreateProperty',
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        'ContentType': 'application/octet-stream'
      },
      // data:{
      //   propertyId: '11',
      //   category: category,
      //   roomType: roomType,
      //   location: location,
      //   amount: price,
      //   thumbnailImageUrl: thumbnailImageUrl,
      //   interiorVideoUrl: interiorVideoUrl,
      //   compoundVideoUrl: compoundVideoUrl,
      //   streetVideoUrl: streetVideoUrl,
      //   isPropertyAvailable: true,
      // }
    })
    .then((res)=>{
      console.log(res)
      alert(res.data.responseMessage)
    })
    .catch((err)=> console.log(err))
  }







return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
          <title>Add New Property</title>
      </Helmet>
      <FormHolder>
        <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} style={{height:'500px'}}>
          <FormOne>
            <label>Category:</label>
            <select value={category} onChange={handleCategoryChange}>
              {categoryOptions.map((item, key) => (
                <option key={key}>{item}</option>
              ))}
            </select>

            <label>Bedrooms:</label>
            <select value={roomType} onChange={handleBedroomsChange}>
              {bedroomsOptions.map((item, key) => (
                <option key={key}>{item}</option>
              ))}
            </select>

            <label>Area:</label>
            <select value={location} onChange={handleAreaChange}>
              {areaOptions.map((item, key) => (
                <option key={key}>{item}</option>
              ))}
            </select>

            <label>Price:</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="price"
              id="price"
              min="100000"
              max="50000000"
              placeholder="Price of property"
              value={price}
              onChange={handlePriceChange}
            ></input>
          </FormOne>

          <FormTwo>
            <BoxOne>
              <BoxOneCont>
                <label>Thumbnail Picture</label>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  name="picture"
                  accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg"
                  // value={thumbnailImageUrl}
                  onChange={handleimgChange}
                ></input>
              </BoxOneCont>
            </BoxOne>
            <BoxTwo>
              <BoxTwoCont>
                <label>Interior Video</label>
                <input 
                type="file" 
                name="intvideo" 
                accept="video/*"
                onChange={handleIntVidChange}
                // value={interiorVideoUrl}
                ></input>
              </BoxTwoCont>
            </BoxTwo>
            <BoxThree>
              <BoxThreeCont>
                <label>Compound Video</label>
                <input 
                type="file" 
                name="compvideo" 
                accept="video/*"
                onChange={handleCompChange}
                ></input>
              </BoxThreeCont>
            </BoxThree>
            <BoxFour>
              <BoxFourCont>
                <label>Street Video</label>
                <input 
                type="file" 
                name="streetvideo" 
                accept="video/*"
                onChange={handleStreetChange}
                ></input>
              </BoxFourCont>
            </BoxFour>
          </FormTwo>

          <div style={{ margin: "auto", width: "365px" }}>
            <Input />
          </div>
        </form>
      </FormHolder>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[console log of FormData()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qslu.png)

[Error message when using FormData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPfDp.png)

I would appreciate if any senior can help me solve this problem as i have spent so many days trying to solve this myself. Thank you.

Comment: This error is because your sever does not support the media type you are sending. Have you tried it before with POSTman ?